# How to get the value of an unknown id using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have tried using the "this" keyqord but I cannot seem to get the value. I need help, thanks!

here is the fragment of my script generating dynamic id.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($deviceID as $row){
        echo '<tr><td><div class="drag" id="bus'.$i.'" value="'.$row['description'].'">'.$row['description'].'</div><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></td></tr>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Here is what I'm trying to do in my javascript.

```
var redips_init;
redips_init = function (i) {
    var rd = REDIPS.drag;
    rd.init();
    rd.drop_option = 'shift';
    rd.animation_shift = true;

    rd.myhandler_dropped = function () { 
        var pos = rd.get_position();            
        msg.innerHTML = 'Changed: ' + pos[1] + ' ' + pos[2];
        alert($(this).val());
    }        
};
```

Comment: How are you attaching the listener? How is it called?

Comment: Where do you mention the element you want to call? `this` is not magic.

Comment: What is `msg` variable referring to.

Comment: @Pushpesh nevermind that, it does something else. I have a loop creating rows and inside that rows is a div which has an ID and a value, I want to get that value but how?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I am not sure.. :( Im just dragging the div and when it drops I want it to show the value of that element but I cant because I cant distingushed what ID that element is holding. :( any algorithm is fine with me. Thanks!

Comment: ok, i see in your php code that the div's have an id like bus0,bus1,bus2 etc... So, you can create a way to pass the desired div's id number to your `redips_init` function. Then you can do `alert( $( 'div#bus' + id ).val() );`, where id is the number of the div (0,1,2..)

Comment: How can I set the value of id..?

Comment: Are you using some kind of plugin to handle the dragged events?

Comment: I already figured it out. sorry for all the troubl. :) The problem why "this" shows undefined is it defines a wrong object. :)

Answer (score -2):

You should try `this.id`

Maybe you can select your element first
`$('selector').attr('id')`

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/argiropoulostauros/Yt68B/)

Comment: Are you serious? `$(this).attr('id')`? `this.id` is more than enough.

Comment: And so does `$(this).attr('id')`.